# Do some built-in functions loop behind the scenes?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-design, compiler, loops

I mostly code in C# & VB, but I think this question is pretty universal. I try to limit loops to increase performance. For instance, string functions that split the string into an array, or do a lookup or replace.

I think if I were to write some string functions with those kinds of capabilities, I would need to include a loop.

Any insights about how what a compiler is doing with, say, a string replace function? Or any examples of how they're written in the programming language?

Comment: What constitutes a 'built in function'?

Comment: Do you know about the opcode set of your target machine? Everything that isn't doable with a fixed string of opcodes from that set **will** require a loop no matter how great a programmer does it. It makes no sense to be worried about "using loops" because they might be slow.

Comment: If I'm writing something in .NET, there are functions that are available to me for string manipulation, data type conversion, etc.

Comment: @JMcD those would be part of the standard library (not so much 'built in').  I would encourage you to read through, say... the [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) class on Java (part of its standard library) and count the loops.

Comment: @MichaelT, thanks for the link. I think that will be very helpful.

Comment: .NET framework source code can be inspected [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very probably, *most* builtin or primitives functions of C# involves some loop (at the [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) level) when executed.

BTW, even the object allocation indirectly involves a loop. At some times, an object allocation could trigger the [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), which is looping.

Notice that a program *without* any loops is a finite state automaton, and will surely terminate (in less than a second, typically - intuitively the CPU is processing more than one instruction per nano-second, and in a few gigabytes you can encode about a billion machine instructions; without loops the processor would interpret then quickly!)

Of course, function calls, in particular [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) function calls, are a way of looping. And [tail-recursive calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) are *exactly* a looping construct (which does not consume any [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) space).

Read also the [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), and about [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), [Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (notably [accidental Turing completeness](http://beza1e1.tuxen.de/articles/accidentally_turing_complete.html) is very funny), [primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function), [random-access machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), ...

BTW, you'll learn a lot by studying the source code of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and Microsoft has even made the [source](http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/) code of [C# open source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). With a Linux system on your laptop you'll have even more free software...

Comment: Wow, you're going to keep me busy here for a while :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess any decent opimizer for almost any (compiled) mainstream programming language includes the well-known technique of [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling). So it is unneccessary in most cases to do this kind of low-level optimization manually, the result of what compilers produce are often better than any "hand coded" solution.

Said that, if you can replace an O(n) algorithm with a loop like

```
 for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    sum+=i;
```

by an O(1) solution without a loop, like

```
 sum+= n*(n+1)/2
```

then I would not expect a typical optimizer to be so smart that to do this automatically.